# How can I join with some invalid characters appended?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join

I have two tables look like this.

```
some                       other
------------------------------------------
some_id BIGINT             other_id BIGINT
                           some_id  VARCHAR
```

The `other.some_id` looks obviously referring `some.some_id`.

Two problems I faced.

- There is no FK.
- The `other.some_id` is VARCHAR
- The `other.some_id`'s value may be string(`''`)
- Some `other.some_id` columns contains a value appended with a new line-character

First three problems seem to be resolved but the third problem I can't solve.

```java
class Other {

    @Valid
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) // -> EAGER!
    @JoinFormula("CASE some_id
                 + " WHEN ''"
                 + " THEN NULL"
                 + " ELSE some_id"
                 + " END")
    @ManyToOne(optional = /*false*/true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//    @JoinColumn(name = "some_id", nullable = false, insertable = false,
//                updatable = false,
//                foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
    private Some some;
}
```

Hibernate fails with those values appended with a new line character.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.DataConversionException:
    Cannot determine value type from string '11111
'
```

As you can see, the `'1111...` part has an trailing new line character.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved with following expression.

```java
    @JoinFormula("CASE some_id"
                 + " WHEN ''"
                 + " THEN NULL"
                 + " ELSE TRIM(BOTH '\n' FROM some_id)"
                 + " END")
```